# File.isDirectory and isFile both false

Tags: java

I'm writing a java application, that lists directory contents.
When it comes to list the directory, the behavior of .isDirectory() method returns false for items, I'm pretty sure are directories.

```
public List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> getNodes(String path)
{
    List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();

    File directory = new File(path).getAbsoluteFile();
    File[] contents = directory.listFiles();

    for (File item : contents)
    {
        if (item.isDirectory())
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(item.getName());
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Placeholder..."));
            nodes.add(node);
        }
        else
        {
            nodes.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(item.getName()));
        }
    }

    return nodes;
}
```

The above code always runs to the else branch.
If I replace the loop, I get an even weirder result:

```
    for (File item : contents)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s - directory? %b file? %b %n", item.getAbsoluteFile().getPath(), item.isDirectory(), item.isFile());
    }
```

The output of this is:

/storage/other - directory? false file? false
/storage/games - directory? false file? false
/storage/apps - directory? false file? false
/storage/testfile - directory? false file? false

if I list the files in the /storage directory, it is clear as day, that all but testfile is a directory.

What am I doing wrong?

---

To avoid confusion, /storage is an actual directory in /. Not a typo.

Comment: Are you sure `item.exists()` is true? `/storage/other` is an _absolute_ path, whereas you probably want the _relative_ path of `storage/other` (note the lack of `/` at the start).

Comment: The items exist, before calling this method, I change the working directory to /storage, so the path is okay, in the "alternative" loop I just tried to see if the working directory did actually change, hence the absolute path.

Comment: An absolute path is relative to the whole filesystem, not relative to your working dir.

Comment: While that is true, If I stand in /directory, and check the absolute path of an item contained here, the absolute path will be /directory/item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was badly configured access permissions.
isDirectory, isFile, and exists will return false, if the user running the application doesn't have execute permissions.